# sending string from C# to client and converting into Uint8Array type byte array and then into blob to open excel file. Corgi Involved

Tags: javascript, c#, utf-8, blob, closedxml

So here in C# code i am sending corgi to client which has corgiBabies. Using ClosedXml here.

```
 var wbCorgiBabiesTemplate = new XLWorkbook();
                var wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate = wbCorgiBabiesTemplate.Worksheets.Add(" Work Sheet Corgi baby Template");
                wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("A1").Value = "Corgi Parent";
                wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("B1").Value = "Corgi Child";

                wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("A2").Value = "Petunia";
                wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("B2").Value = "Khaleesi";

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wbCorgiBabiesTemplate.SaveAs(ms);
                   byte[]  Corgibabies = ms.ToArray();
                }
       corgi.Corgibabies = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Corgibabies);
            
         return corgi;
```

After that in Client i want to open corgibabies in excel sheet but the conversion here is wrong somewhere i think that excel sheet doesn't open correctly.

```
var fileName = 'CorgiBabies.xlsx';

     dataAccessService.get('corgi')
            .then(function(response) {
                let utf8Encode = new TextEncoder();
                var strBytes = utf8Encode.encode(response.corgiBabies);
            
                    var a = document.createElement("a");
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.style = "display: none";
                    
                    var file = new Blob([strBytes], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
                    var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                    a.href = fileURL;
                    a.download = fileName;
                    a.click();
                
            })
```

Below what excel sheet gives me error in image

[image]

Comment: Your spreadsheet is corrupted.  My guess is that you're not following the Open XML specification when you make your `a` element.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what specification i am not following here?

Comment: The Open XML Specification.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk

Comment: i looked at it ..i have no idea where those rules are in there

Comment: You aren't likely to get a proper answer to this without a bit more code/detail - like (I assume) that you are using Microsoft's Open XML SDK (if so, see [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/structure-of-a-spreadsheetml-document][1] for sample code for creating a `Workbook`, then you'll get the idea and will be able to understand adding `Worksheet`s/`Sheets`s and adding value/s to them). If `response.corgiBabies` is a `string` I'm pretty sure the explicit UTF8 encoding won't be necessary either but hey you'll find that out when you get there.

Comment: If you are going to be running on a Windows server and have the MS Office license, you may well find it easier to work directly with `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` (COM interface).

Comment: @AlanK i am using closedXml for creating workbook in C#. For Blob I need Byte Array. So i think that ITF8 encoding is necessary? i will try to add more code for closed Xml

Comment: @AlanK added code for closedXml

Answer (score 1):

`ClosedXML` has several extensions that will help you acheive what you need :

- [ClosedXML.Extensions.AspNet](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Extensions.AspNet)
- [ClosedXML.Extensions.Mvc](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Extensions.Mvc)
- [ClosedXML.Extensions.WebApi](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML.Extensions.WebApi)

You can install the appropriate extension for your project, to help give you a fast access to download the workbook. You can also save the file on disk, and pass the file link (path) to JavaScript, and continue your work on the file from JavaScript.

if you need to know how you would let the user download the file from ASP.NET,
then you can do this :

Simple workbook :

**C#: ASP.NET MVC**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Download(string fileName)
{
    // create workbook 
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var sheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");
    sheet.Cell("A1").Value = "A1";
    sheet.Cell("B1").Value = "B1";
    sheet.Cell("A2").Value = "A2";
    sheet.Cell("B2").Value = "B2";
    
    // get workbook bytes 
    byte[] workbookBytes;
    
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        workbookBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
    }

    return File(workbookBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
}
```

**C#: ASP.NET Web Forms**

```
public void Export(HttpResponse response, string fileName)
{
    // create workbook 
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
    var sheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Worksheet 1");
    sheet.Cell("A1").Value = "A1";
    sheet.Cell("B1").Value = "B1";
    sheet.Cell("A2").Value = "A2";
    sheet.Cell("B2").Value = "B2";

    HttpResponse httpResponse = response;
    httpResponse.Clear();
    httpResponse.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    httpResponse.AddHeader("content-disposition", $"attachment;filename=\"{fileName}.xlsx\"");

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        workbook.SaveAs(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.WriteTo(httpResponse.OutputStream);
    }

    httpResponse.End();
}
```

the above examples will directly download the file into the client device. However, if you want to pass the workbook bytes to the JavaScript, you will need to convert it to base64 string and pass it to the `JavaScript` like so :

```
var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(workbookBytes);
```

Then from `JavaScript` decode it to `Uint8Array` :

```
/*
    JavaScript
*/
// get base64 string array and decoded it
var data = atob(serverSideResult);

var array = new Array(data.length);

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    array[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}

// final result
var dataUint8Array = new Uint8Array(array);
```

now you can work with `dataUint8Array` as normal `Uint8Array`.

if you want to pass it back to the server-side, you can convert the array to base64 string, and pass it to the server-side like so :

```
/*
    JavaScript
*/
let binaryString = ''

for (var i = 0; i < dataUint8Array.byteLength; i++) {
    binaryString += String.fromCharCode(dataUint8Array[i]);
}
//pass base64Result to the server-side (C#)
var base64Result = window.btoa(binaryString);
```

then from `C#` you just need to convert it back to array from base64 string like so :

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dataReceivedFromJavaScript);
```

where `bytes` would be `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on .Net Core+ (otherwise you can find the System.Buffers Nuget package for .Net standard or framework), on server side try

```
using System.Buffers; 
using System.Buffers.Text;
```

and insert

```
var outputBuffer = new Span<byte>();
var status = Base64.EncodeToUtf8(Corgibabies, outputBuffer, out var consumed, out var written);
// sanity check
// if (status != OperationStatus.Done) throw new Exception();`

// do the above just before replacing
// System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Corgibabies);

// with
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBuffer);
```

Now I'm pretty certain that will ensure that the server responds with what the client should expect but I'm not set up to test the Javascript side of things (yet).  In the meantime let me know if this helps you make progress.

PS1: the error in your original code was the implicit assumption that `Corgibabies` is an array containing the bytes of a UTF8 encoded string.  It actually contains the raw bytes of what would normally be an .xlsx file on disk.  What is needed is to make that into text (Base64 encoding) and ensure that text is UTF8.  Obviously in the Javascript you need to do the reverse - UTF8 Base64 to binary, save to disk, open in Excel...

Comment: GetString cannot take output buffer as input. As it says cannot convert System.span<byte> to byte[]. A type conversion is required here? @alanK

Comment: And if you use `outputBuffer.ToArray()`? We're obviously not playing with the same versions of everything. If it works I'll update my answer.

Comment: Don't have too much time to work on this due to other tasks. will have to get back to this again when i have time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning `string` as the Content, you can make it work with `File`.

```
        public ActionResult Get()
        {
            var wbCorgiBabiesTemplate = new XLWorkbook();
            var wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate = wbCorgiBabiesTemplate.Worksheets.Add(" Work Sheet Corgi baby Template");
            wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("A1").Value = "Corgi Parent";
            wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("B1").Value = "Corgi Child";

            wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("A2").Value = "Petunia";
            wsCoriBabiesAmendementTemplate.Cell("B2").Value = "Khaleesi";
            wbCorgiBabiesTemplate.SaveAs("new.xlsx");
            var ms = new MemoryStream();
           wbCorgiBabiesTemplate.SaveAs(ms);

            ms.Position = 0;
            var fileName = "CorgiBabies.xlsx";
            return File(ms, "application/octet-stream", fileName);
        }
```

Api call:

```
<a href="https://localhost:7135/api/downloadExcel"></a>
```

or

```
fetch('https://localhost:7135/api/downloadExcel')
  .then(resp => resp.blob())
  .then(blob => {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = url;
    // the filename you want
    a.download = 'CorgiBabies.xlsx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  })
  .catch(() => alert('oh no!'));
```

Ref: [git](https://github.com/rkbbd/ClosedXml-)